# Is there a way to view full file paths using net file?

Tags: windows, command-line, network-shares

Using the [net file command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_file.mspx?mfr=true) in Windows, I can view all open shared files on a server. A maddening shortcoming of this tool is that it only displays truncated file paths, so if I have multiple files with the same *name* in a number of different *directories* (e.g., a directory for each date for the past 30 days), it's next to impossible to figure out which one is open.

Is there a way to get these full file paths to show? Or is there some other tool (besides net file) that I can use to view open shared files with full file paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PsFile`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx)

Comment: Wow, right under my nose the whole time (I'd already been using *other* programs from PsTools for other purposes—just missed this one somehow). This is perfect; thanks!